# Start an application on VirtualBox Virtual machine from Host machine Command Line

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I would like to start an application from my Host machine on my Virtual machine. To be more precise, I have a python script which starts Firefox Browser several times; each time with a different url, and I want to be able to execute that script directly from my host machine command line; in order to open the browser on my virtual machine.

P.S: Both my host machine and my VM have Ubuntu 18.04 installed

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Over 30 years ago, one could do remote execution with UUCP using the uux(1) command. Looks like it is still around.